# My Eclipse console display terrible characters since I switched to Logback ? (Spring boot project)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, encoding, console, logback

Since I added a logback.xml to log, my console display weird characters, making it unreadable.

But when I launch my project since a command console, evrything works fine.

How can it is possible to fix it ?

[image]

Thank you for your help

Joss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\e[0;39m is a value of a color in Linux's terminals color system.
This specific value corresponds to a kind of blue.
Here is a reference : https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

You can try to adjust Eclipse Settings of the console to a Windows compatible output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to print colored log, but it is not supported.

That was my fix:

1. Go to application.yml
2. Find this:

spring:
output:
ansi:
enabled:
always

And change "always" to "never".

Taken from first example here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/color-logs.html